# Can a sequence of "automatic" tasks be seen in an EEG?

Tags: eeg, unconscious, automaticity

Say I train a task that consists of a sequence of smaller events a 1000 times such that it becomes an automatic/subconscious (something like muscle memory) movement. Then when I view the EEG signal during this automatic task (assuming this task consists of 3 small events) will I be able to see/decode instances of the second and third event once the first event is finished by the user?
It is basically sequential decoding of future automatic events.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "events"? There are "EEG events" that happen prior to action. For example, alpha could reflect motor preparation https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3418545/

Comment: @noumenal by an event, I meant a motor action. You can consider three events like a punch, kick and a squat if repeated in sequence a lot of times would become automatic(or at least that is my assumption).

Comment: @noumenal Like you mentioned, I understand that there are "events" that happen prior to each action. But is there any way to predict that the "subject" will do a kick/squat right after he does a punch? Will I be able to detect variations in the signal to detect such a thing?

Comment: @Roshan See the answer by noumenal.

Comment: You can edit your question to include your clarification. If there is an EEG event associated with the entire hybrid movement, it is possible that this pattern could be characterized already at the first behavioral event, but if it was a question for an experiment, one would have to ask: "In comparison to what?" Let's say you train two people. Before training, the sequence is not stored as a motor program. (An untrained person would not exhibit such a pattern for the first event, but a trained person would) Would knowledge of the first person's EEG help us predict the EEG of the second person?

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is that it depends on:

- training protocol (duration, frequency)
- modality (hearing, seeing, memorizing, attention, etc)
- individual variance (observable changes varies between individuals - some may not respond to the training)

So it has to be determined individually for each task (not enough information provided in the original question). In other words, it is an empirical question, which means that the answer lies in the results of an experiment - ”we have to check”.

Comment: Could you please explain that in layman terms.

Comment: I asked if you could see instances of the second/third event in the signal of the first event which I don't think is explained in your answer.